# How to add column with a specific value over a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes. I want to add a column to each dataframe with a fixed value. Here is the planned input of the function:

ar_data <- add_cols(ar_data, c("Data_source1", "Data_source2", "Data_source3"))

For example, the first dataframe in the list of dataframes (ar_data) needs a column added (the column is to be named 'type' across all dataframes in the list) with a value of "Data_source1". The second dataframe in the list will have a column added with a value of "Data_source2", and so on...

Here is my attempted function:

```
add_cols <- function(data, col_value) {
  data <- map2(data, col_value, function(x, y) x['type'] = y)
  return(data)
}
```

However it is not working as planned. Any ideas why?

Comment: `?mapply` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` :

```
add_cols <- function(data, col_value) {
   Map(cbind, data, type = col_value)
   #Using `map2` from `purrr`
   #purrr::map2(data, col_value, ~cbind(.x, type = .y))
}

add_cols(ar_data, c("Data_source1", "Data_source2", "Data_source3"))
```

---

In your attempt, you need to return the data frame back after adding a column. So this should work.

```
data <- map2(data, col_value, function(x, y) {x['type'] = y;x})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(data), function(i) transform(data[[i]], type = col_value[i]))
```